# Ionic media plugin does not play locally stored mp3 files on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic3, ionic-native-media

I'm trying to make a mp3 player with ionic media plugin.
First I download song on local storage via path

```
let filePath;

if(this.platform.is('android'))
{
    filePath = this.file.externalDataDirectory;
}
else 
{
  filePath = this.file.documentsDirectory;
}

filePath = filePath +'810.mp3';
```

after that we get such path

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5DC6D2D0-6336-4C6E-A39E-5D5FD7D8AF7B/Library/Cloud/810.mp3

So for example we have such an object

```
track = {

    'name':'Name of Song',
    'filePath': filePath
}
```

I create

```
const file:MediaObject = this.media.create(track.filePath);
```

and when time comes to play

```
file.play();
```

Whole app crashes without giving me a hint of error. 
This plugin normally plays files on Android from both localPath and internetPath.
On iOS it plays only from internet but crashes when plays local files. Please help.

Comment: You can check `file.onSuccess.subscribe(() => console.log('Action is successful'));`

`file.onError.subscribe(error => console.log('Error!', error));` to check what error you are getting while playing it locally.

Comment: I tried to use both. But they just don't fire. Though music plays fine on android without them. Thank you for fixing my question by the way.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution. It was here.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-9-cant-play-audio-video-files-that-are-downloaded-to-device/37580

For example.

```
track = {    
    'name':'Name of Song',
    'filePath': '';
}

if(this.platform.is('android'))
{
  track.filePath = this.file.externalDataDirectory;
}
else 
{
  track.filePath = this.file.documentsDirectory;
}

track.filePath = track.filePath +'810.mp3';

const transfer = this.transfer.create();

let url = "http://someLink.com/someFileName.mp3";

transfer.download(url, track.filePath).then((entry)=>{

// **code here will be executed when track is downloaded**
// and only for ios local file system we need to create a special link to this file 
// so that  cordova media plugin could read this file and if necessary to delete it 
// with cordova file plugin by this link also.

if(this.platform.is('ios'))
   this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(track.filePath).then((entry)=>{
     track.filePath = entry.toInternalURL;
   });
```

Actually there was another way to make iOS play file by removinh **file://** from beging of track.filePath but then you will face with another issue. You won't be able do delete it by this path later.